# Select columns by matching column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd df and I want to select one of the columns by matching the column names.

For example, if I have a defined value called "division =2". I want to use that to select related column from the following table. In this case, I want to get column df.iloc[:, 2].

How do I do this?

```
 division=2 

        Year       1        2          3       4
  0     2024      1.007351 1.098082 1.033620   0.938746
  1     2025      1.023808 1.117399 1.036366   0.936205
  2     2026      1.036785 1.133247 1.040184   0.934735
```

Comment: Do you mean `df.iloc[:, division]`, since `division` is defined as `2`?  Please clarify.

Comment: division could be any random number from 1 to 4 based on random sampling. My actual data has census divisions from 1 to 9.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @S3DEV, thank you! You are correct. I tried your code -- price_trend=eg_price_trend.iloc[:,division] and I got the values based on the selected division.

Comment: @Spring - No worries.  I've just posted this as the answer.  Please vote and mark as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: does `df[division]` not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You are **very nearly** there!  See below.  You can use your `division` variable in place of the column name (or locator, in this case).

**A word of caution:**
It's important to note, the difference in *column name* and *locator*.  The OP asks for column name but is using the locator (`df.iloc`) in the question.

**Locator:**
`.iloc[:, 2]` will return all rows in the **third column** (numbering starts at 0).  And this can vary as this DataFrame was created via a `dict`, which **does not retain order**.

**Column Name:**
`df[2]` or `df.loc[:, 2]` will return all rows in the **column named 2**.

```
import pandas as pd

division = 2
data = {'Year': [2024, 2025, 2026],
        1: [1.007351, 1.023808, 1.036785],
        2: [1.098082, 1.117399, 1.133247],
        3: [1.033620, 1.036366, 1.040184],
        4: [0.938746, 0.936206, 0.934735]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Display DataFrame
print(df)
# 1) Display the output of column named 2.
print(df[division])
# 2) Display the output of column 2.
print(df.iloc[:, division])
```

DataFrame contents:

```
          1         2         3         4  Year
0  1.007351  1.098082  1.033620  0.938746  2024
1  1.023808  1.117399  1.036366  0.936206  2025
2  1.036785  1.133247  1.040184  0.934735  2026
```

1) Output for column name:

```
print(df[division])
0    1.098082
1    1.117399
2    1.133247
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

2) Output for column locator:

```
print(df.iloc[:, division])
0    1.033620
1    1.036366
2    1.040184
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```